# SwiftUI: View_Preview error: Missing argument for parameter 'x' in call

Tags: xcode, swiftui, arguments, preview

I a receiving the following complier error in the View_Preview section of code:  "Missing argument for parameter 'userInfo' in call".

Xcode suggests the following fix: "(userInfo: [Employee])", however this fix gives the following complier error: "Cannot convert value of type '[Employee].Type' to expected argument type '[Employee]'"

Here is my view code:

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var pilot: Pilot

let userInfo: [Employee]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        List {
            ForEach(userInfo, id: \.age) {line in
                EmployeeCardView(employee: line)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct EmployeeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    EmployeeView()                //ERROR here 
        .environmentObject(Pilot)
}
}
```

Here is my data model code:

```
struct Employee: Identifiable, Codable {
var id = UUID()
var age: Int
var yearGroup: Int
var category: String

init(age: Int, yearGroup: Int, category: String) {
    self.age = age
    self.yearGroup = yearGroup
    self.category = category
}
}

@MainActor class Pilot: ObservableObject {
@Published var pilot: Employee

init(pilot: Employee) {
    self.pilot = pilot
}
var pilotInfo: [Employee] = [
Employee(age: 35, yearGroup: 1, category: "B717")]
}
```

I also tried this:

[image: Employee().pilotInfo]

Is there an apple tutorial that explains the logic of this aspect of View_Previews?

Comment: Try `EmployeeView(userInfo: Employee().pilotInfo)`

Comment: @vacawama Thank you for responding!  I tried and got three errors: 1. Missing argument 'from' in call   2. Type 'Pilot.type' cannot conform to 'Observable Object'    3. Value of type 'Employee' has no member 'pilotInfo'.  I included a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: @vacawama Any other ideas?

Comment: Pilot with an uppercase is a type not a value you need to create a pilot, same for the employee you need to fill the variables for the initializer

Answer (score 0):

The errors aren't very helpful, I believe it's a matter of initialization of @State and other parameters. Without initialization / default values - the constructor fails